# how to get type of popup dialog by Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the chrome extension, I add this:

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function(sender, method, params){

if(method == "Page.javascriptDialogOpening") {

    console.log(params.message);
    }
}
```

In this way, chrome extension can get the content of dialog, for example:

When chrome page show alert dialog (like "hello world"), console will show the alert content by params.message (which is a string "hello world").  the same as prompt dialog and confirm dialog.

But how can I get the type of dialog?

I mean, when a dialog pops up, the chrome extension can get dialog type like "alert", "prompt" or "confirm".

PS:In old ways, I use plugin to get dialog type by get windows dialog type. but as the chrome version goes up, this way failed, seems like that dialog are not show as window dialog but contained in webpage.